# Code block with Kramdown, modified in Liquid

Tags: wordpress, markdown, jekyll, liquid, kramdown

I want to move my posts from WordPress to Jekyll and i have a problem with code blocks. I wrote code for replacing original formatting tags with Kramdown tags, but the page does not recognize the formatting marks and treats it like text.
Here is code:

```
{{ content | replace: '[code language=”csharp”]', '~~~<br>' | replace: '[/code]', '<br>~~~'  }}
```

its replacing the original code but it doesn't recognize the formatting pattern. Maybe i need to update it after formation? or is there a method for reformatting markdown text? Or can i perform this operation before converting to HTML? I want to write one method that works for all post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this replace, it is too late for the Markdown converter to pickup this change.

To make this work the way you want to do, you would have [write a plugin](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#converters) that performs the replace before the Markdown converter runs.

However, assuming you don't want to use `[code]` for new posts, it would be much easier to do a one-time search/replace on the Markdown files directly, which you already created from your Wordpress blog.

i.e. open all files in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (or similar text editor), and do a search/replace across all files.